# Reloading Qt plugins on the fly

Tags: qt, plugins

My program makes use of QPluginLoader to dynamically load plugins on request.
What I would like to happen is that if a plugin is changed, it is automatically reloaded, so they are added to a QFileSystemWatcher. If it detects that the plugin has been changed, the QPluginLoader unloads it and deletes itself, and after waiting a few seconds, a new QPluginLoader is created that loads the updated plugin.

The problem is that the plugin still appears to be the previous version; it does not reflect any of the changes, as if the new QPluginLoader just retrieved a cached version or something.

There's not much to see in the code, but it's available on request.

Any idea how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: This will not work since you can't make sure that nothing refers to the old plugin stuff anymore. Therefore QPluginLoader does not really unload a plugin until program shutdown.

Comment: Hmm, that's disappointing. Incidentally I saw this in the documentation: "Once loaded, plugins remain in memory until all instances of QPluginLoader has been unloaded, or until the application terminates."

Comment: It's simple a problem of your app. You add functionality to your program with the plugin and then must make sure that nothing references the plugin code anymore when you want to unload them which is nearly impossible (and if it's only a pointer to some data provided by your plugin). Therefore unloading plugins on the fly is not really possible in every program. Except the plugin has minimal functionality.